# How to get current editing customer

Tags: magento-1.7, customer

how can I get customer currently being edited?
I'm developing a plugin with UI on customer edit page.

Thanks.

Comment: is this from the front end or the back end of magento?

Comment: next time please clear your question.

Comment: I believe question is clear enough, there are not much customer edit pages on front end are there..? Question was also answered very fast, that was really thrilling, i see no reason to deal with this anymore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In frontend:

```
$customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
```

In admin panel, on customer edit page:

```
$customer = Mage::registry('current_customer');
```